# Where to add javascript Code of issuing identity on hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I think I am missing something but I do not know where the code from here 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue.html
should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no problem.

They're intended for use from client applications that want to 'consume' the business network (ie already deployed), ie for creating business network cards containing [issued] blockchain identities (these come from a CA server under the covers when the Composer JS API 'identity issue' is invoked - the CA server issues the actual certificates and that is combined with business network metadata to create a business network card)

The Javascript APIs / programmatic examples are when using composer-client - ie issuing identities programmatically from a client application (eg Angular-based user registration module in an app etc etc).

So an example might be where once a user is registered, you can have the 'card' creation process automated, such that they can then import to their wallet and connect to the business network. See https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/pii-network/test/pii.js#L134 (FileCardStore (for storing cards on disk) would replace MemoryCardStore in this example, and the `ImportCardForIdentity` is a function defined further up FYI and 'alice' is the 'admin' card (in this tutorial) that is creating participants / issuing identities and then creating cards / importing them.

Another useful example here in this blog posted on the community -> https://www.skcript.com/svr/how-to-build-nodejs-application-for-your-hyperledger-composer-networks/ and

This tutorial https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc shows how you can use the REST APIs to create your identities from a dedicated issuer REST server. And them (just as you would from a client application), authenticate as a REST client and interact in multi-user mode with the business network, using the identities that were issued in the tutorial to call queries etc.